# Calling different function depending on which field has input

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a calculator which call different function depending on which field has entry in it.
"initial_hosts" has to have an entry then the user can enter values in  "Time" OR "Num" but not both (error message).

If a Value is entered in "Time" when the "Calculate" is clicked I would like it to call function number() and if "Num" call function timeCal()

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function timeCal(){
    a=Number(document.calculator.initial_hosts.value);
    b=Number(document.calculator.Num.value);
    // Example of cal
    c=a*b;
    document.calculator.total.value=c;
  }
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function number(){
    a=Number(document.calculator.initial_hosts.value);
    b=Number(document.calculator.Time.value);
    // Example of cal
    c=a*b;
    document.calculator.total.value=c;
  }
</script>

<div class="figure2"> 
  <form name ="calculator" class="form">
    <p>You can use the calculator below to see the approximate number of infected hosts after a given amount of time </p>
    <label for="Fname">initial hosts:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="initial_hosts"/><br/>

    <label for="Fname">Trigger Date:</label><br/>
    <input type="text"  id="TTime" value="" />
    <br/><br/>

    <font face="arial, helvetica" size="2" >Note: Enter the time space or the number of targets </font><br/>

    <label for="Time">Enter Time:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="Time"/><br/>

    <label for="Num">Target Number :</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="Num"/><br/>

    <label for="total">Outcome:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="total"/><br />
    <br/>

    <p><input type="button" style="height: 35px; width: 100px" value="Calculate"  onclick="javascript:timeCal();"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have no idea how I can go about this, Thank you in advance :)

Comment: did the accepted answer work for when none of the two field has value? I think not. please recheck. or correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new function called `calculate();` and from there you check which field has data in it.

```
function calculate() {
   if (document.calculator.time.value != ""){
       timeCal();
   }else {
       number();
   }
}
```

and change your button to run calculate();

```
<input type="button" style="height: 35px; width: 100px" value="Calculate"  onclick="javascript:calculate();"/>
```

Comment: when none of this two field has value then your function also calls `number()`. Is this okay? Otherwise, my answer is right in a better sense. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @sarwar026 you are right, i am sure the OP can get it from here

Comment: @sarwar026 your solution is correct too beside missing brackets :), Thank you :) and thank you lbu

Comment: @Badr: Thanks for noticing the missing bracket. But you didn't get my point, i think.

Comment: @sarwar026 I do understand your point I have added else if instead of else to check if they are both empty or one an not the other, and an else to flag if both empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    function callAppropriateFunction(){
        numValue=document.calculator.Num.value;
        timeValue=document.calculator.Time.value;  
        if(numValue!='')
            number();
        else if(timeValue!='')
            timeCal();
        else
            alert("please select either number or time");
    }
</script>


<input type="button" style="height: 35px; width: 100px" value="Calculate"  onclick="javascript:callAppropriateFunction();"/>
```